# Visual Studio Development Server (2010) and NTLM authorization

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, ntlm

I'm using Visual Studio Development Server (Visual Basic 2010) and it works fine. Now I've enabled NTLM Authorization because I want to test the website using a different user account. Now when I try to access the website I always get the following error page:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden.

---

Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

I'm using a test account which is a normal user within our domain. I've already set the access rights in my project folder to Full Access for this user but it does not help. Any further ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option that doesn't require running VS as Administrator, or setting up local IIS is to ensure Visual Studio 2010 is on Service Pack 1, is to go grab IIS Express, available here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038

This is a version of IIS that runs in user mode, that can handle things like authentication, serving requests to remote hosts, etc. In short, you have the full request pipeline, just like in full IIS. Once installed, when you right click on a web project, there will be a new menu option "Use IIS Express". This will configure the project to use IIS express and set up the bindings for it.

More information about from ScottGu here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think it happens because studio development server is very poor. i mean it hasn't all features like a usual iis has. so i made workaround:
(of course you should have iis server on you compure. i'm using iis 7 on win 7)

1. in programs and features -> turn windows features on or off choice
   internet information services -> world wide web services -> security
   -> request filtering
2. in iis create new site than in authentication settings enabled  windows authentication and disabled anonymous authentication
3. start studio as administrator in project properties
   -> web select use local iis server choice server that you created above press create virtual directory
4. (optional) in web config add
   this to system.web section